Trying to open a new Google Cloud account, being forced to sign up for Google Workspace
The company i work for uses a google account per project, mostly to limit the blast radius if an account is hacked.
This morning I need to start a new project, so i head to https://cloud.google.com/
Create account... for work or business.
Usually I can just enter the new email, but this morning i get stuck. Either accept a @gmail.com address or mandatory signing up for Google Work space.
I need to use a company provided email so notifications from Google are handled, but i cant without signing up for Work spaces.
Anyone know a way to get around this sales flow and back to creating a new cloud account?

I need to use a company provided email so notifications from Google are handled, but i cant without signing up for Work spaces.

Which Google Accounts account are you logged in with (Gmail or corporate email)?

@JohnHanley It happens if in a private window (not logged in at all + no cookies). Same if logged in with an existing account that is corporate or logged in with a gmail account. We dont have any email hosted at Google, we just have stand alone accounts using corp email that are used for GCP.

Your comment wording confuses me. Please update your question with more details.
